# How strong would a realistically evolved orc be?

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, humanoid, strength

In my worlds Orcs are species/subspecies that branched away from homo sapiens in response to evolutionary pressure to be more powerful and more adept at surviving in a much more hostile environment.

They have fangs, dense musculature and bones (2-3x human bone density), a heightened metabolism, improved regeneration and with a slightly higher proportion of fast twitch muscles than humans.

They are 1.9-2.4m tall, and weigh between 125-200kg. (Adjusted weight to be more in line with the typical humanoid form.)
They would likely need 3-5x the calorific intake to maintain their bodyweight, potentially more in a hunter-gatherer lifestyle.

While larger, they still maintain the classic human form, and tend towards lean muscular builds.

How strong would these Orcs be, and how quickly would they be able to sprint?

Comment: *How strong* was Andre the Giant? We don't know and we probably never will know what someone that size can lift. *They would likely need* a sixer just to get out of bed... of forties. That's also about how long they can live.

Comment: [Hafþór Júlíus Björnsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haf%C3%BE%C3%B3r_J%C3%BAl%C3%ADus_Bj%C3%B6rnsson) 205cm, 210 kg

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvZxTBqY278 shows him running, which he has a hard time with. Though to be fair he doesn't train for running at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Strength

Your orcs are in about the same weight range as silverback gorillas. Also gorillas aren't that far away from the human genetic wise, making them a good base comparsion.

> The silverbacks are in fact stronger than 20 adult humans combined as
> they can lift or throw up to 815 kgs while a well-trained man can only
> lift up to 400 kgs. Any adult gorilla can lift up to 450 kilograms,
> not with a body size that can go as high as 200kgs.

With dedicated training in strenght the strongest of the orcs would even outlift that by 2 - 3 times.

### Speed

If we stay with gorillas, they are about as fast on flat ground as humans are. However running upright on two feet would take their powerful arms out of the equation so an upright running orc-gorilla would probably be somewhat slower than humans and quicker exhausted. However you could redirect some of the muscle mass from the arms to the legs for your orcs and have them at the same speed again but only about as strong as ~10-15 regular men.

### Drag

Moving fast is mostly a matter of drag (and mass to an extend), as drag grows exponentially with speed. Twice the speed => 4 times the drag => also 4 times the energy needed.
With the orcs having about twice the weight and probably also about twice the frontal area, they would already need 4 times the energy of a human to move just as fast (30kph). So they need legs with 4 times the muscle capacity (not mass) and also burn 4 times the energy (hence the faster exhaustion mentioned above). An orc going 60kph would need 16x the muscle capacity and energy of a human going 30kph.
Also up against strong wind the orcs will be just outrun by humans.

If you want them to sprint really fast you should let them get exhausted really quickly, keeping humans the better long distance runners (one of the few things humans are actually really good at except using our thumbs)

Comment: How much faster could they sprint than humans if their strength was reduced to something in the range of 5x human? With slightly reduced mass too. I know there are mechanical limits to humanoid locomotion, but is somewhere in the realm of 50-60km/h plausible?

Comment: An easy place to start would be cycling websites - their performance is usually measured in wattage, and the data correlating speed (primary limiter is drag) and power output should be well-documented. Just scale up a runner's wattage by your desired strength factor and go from there

Comment: @Spoon The biggest problem with moving fast is drag. And upright movement is like the worst you can do in regards to drag. at 30-40kph drag already becomes quite noticable (just try running as fast as you can and you will notice the upcoming wind noticably, or try running against heavy wind for that matter). If we then factor in that orcs at their height and obvious bulky stature will have probably 2-2.5 times the frontal area. Also as the nature of drag is, doubling the speed is quadrupling the drag. (cont)

Comment: (cont) If we also factor in the increased weight (again ~2x) an orc needs about 4-5 times as many energy to go just as fast as a human (~30kph) and would need 16-20 times the energy to go 60 kph instead.

Answer (score 3):

There is no hard defined direct correlation between the body size and the strength of the creature. A notorious example is given by [chimpanzee](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/why-are-chimpanzees-stronger-than-humans-1379994/), which despite being smaller than humans, are stronger:

> A chimpanzee had, pound for pound, as much as twice the strength of a human when it came to pulling weights. The apes beat us in leg strength, too, despite our reliance on our legs for locomotion. A 2006 study found that bonobos can jump one-third higher than top-level human athletes, and bonobo legs generate as much force as humans nearly two times heavier.

This gives you room for tuning the strength to what your story needs, without sounding too implausible: for example you can scale it up linearly with the body mass, or to some power of the ratio.

Comment: The reason for this is the balance of fast twitch and slow twitch muscles. Since these Orcs have a similar but small (what is small?) increase in fast twitch they would be slightly stronger than average but still closer to humans than Chimpansees. Although I would find it more logical if Orcs had more Chimpansee like strength at a loss of their more coordinated movements and lower endurance.

Answer (score 1):

At this weight and height, your Orcs would not be lean. They would resemble professional sumo wrestlers, many of whom do in fact fall into the Orc's height/weight brackets, if towards the bottom ends of those. They also train (i.e. perform heavy physical exercise) several hours per day, every day, and consume about 3x the average human's calorific intake. All this makes them very strong and muscular *and fat*. Incidentally, being fat would be *good* for the Orcs: the fat is an insulation, a protective layer and a portable energy storage rolled into one. They could use all three to help them survive in their hostile environment.

The muscular strength is very closely related to the cross-section of the muscle in question, so with Orcs being about 3 times the human's weight and thus having about 3 times the human's muscle, it would on average be some 3 times stronger. (On average, that is, across all of the Orc's muscles; some of them would be better developed than their human equivalents and therefore more than 3 times stronger, while others will be proportionately less developed.)

Sumo wrestlers can sprint, [but aren't particularly good at it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27T4TIra9pI), taking about 8 seconds to complete a 50-meter course in this example.

Comment: Perhaps my weight estimate was a bit high, but I was calculating the skeleton as being significantly heavier (2-3 times the bone density) which is roughly an extra 50-60 kg of bone mass. And at the upper end an 240cm tall humanoid would have a healthy weight of 140kg.  

I can see them fattening up for the winter (seasons last around a year in my world) and hibernating/semi-hibernating to preserve energy.